# moveit getJacobian

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I had a problem with moveit's computeVariableVelocity, which I tracked down to a weird Jacobian matrix in my model.
The robot has X, Y and Z prismatic joints, then a Z revolute. But with the joint-states all zeroed out, I'm getting a jacobian

```
  1.304  0.31889  0.41454        0
  -0.03  0.97173 -0.06256    0.575
0.19219  0.23349  2.48029        0
      0        0        0        0
      0        0        0        0
      0        0        0        1
```

which looks very wrong in a bunch of ways (not least, 1m of Z joint movement turns into 2.4m of worldspace Z!). Only the final revolute joint looks right.

Stepping into getJacobian, things seem to go wrong around line 1161:

```
joint_transform = reference_transform * getGlobalLinkTransform(link);
joint_axis = joint_transform * static_cast<const robot_model::PrismaticJointModel*>(pjm)->getAxis();
```

When I hit this line, getGlobalLinkTransform returns a valid matrix that includes translation. There's nothing in reference transform to cancel this out, so prismatic axis gets rotated *and translated*, and joint_axis ends up totally wonky.

Is there something wrong with my RobotModel here? Am I misunderstandingt the Jacobian?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310489/moveit-getjacobian/) by [Mike Ferenduros](https://answers.ros.org/users/38973/mike-ferenduros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
If you feel this is an issue with MoveIt, I would suggest to report it over at [ros-planning/moveit/issues](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues).

If you do, please try to include a reproducable example or nr of steps. That will greatly simplify debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out it was indeed a moveit bug, fixed last month.
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/commit/ece11fe5ebbfb0f9caeb112c0adf9536bbb915ce

---

Originally posted by [Mike Ferenduros](https://answers.ros.org/users/38973/mike-ferenduros/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-12**:
Thanks for reporting back.